# How to tell systemd to stop service when it no longer required/wanted

Tags: linux, systemd, games

I have 10 TF2 game dedicated servers. They are started manually one by one with individual service files

```
tf2-server-1.service
...
tf2-server-10.service
```

And they want service hlstatsx

```
Wants=hlstatsx.service
```

so it starts when at least one game server starts.

How can I tell systemd to stop the hlstatsx service when none of game servers are running?

I tried option in hlstatsx.service

```
PartOf=tf2-server-1.service tf2-server-2.service tf2-server-3.service tf2-server-4.service tf2-server-5.service tf2-server-6.service tf2-server-7.service tf2-server-8.service tf2-server-9.service tf2-server-10.service
```

but it's stopping hlstatsx.service when one of game servers turned off, but others still running. It is not what I need.

Comment: Have you looked into `PartOf`? (Also, should that be `Requires`?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the directive [`StopWhenUnneeded=yes`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#StopWhenUnneeded=) in the dependency target unit file (i. e. `hlstatsx.service`).